# PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable (install ipopt error)

Tags: macos, python-3.7, pkg-config, ipopt

I tried to install `ipopt` trough `pip install ipopt`

Here is my error:

```
    Collecting ipopt
  Using cached ipopt-0.2.0.tar.gz (162 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-install-i9o4pqdg/ipopt/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-install-i9o4pqdg/ipopt/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_gej3ysb
         cwd: /private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-install-i9o4pqdg/ipopt/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Package ipopt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `ipopt.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'ipopt' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-install-i9o4pqdg/ipopt/setup.py", line 102, in <module>
        **pkgconfig('ipopt'))]
      File "/private/var/folders/3w/zf3x85h55tv7qk2yg8ykztwc0000gn/T/pip-install-i9o4pqdg/ipopt/setup.py", line 58, in pkgconfig
        raise OSError(msg.format(list(packages)))
    OSError: pkg-config was not able to find any of the requested packages ['ipopt'] on your system. Make sure pkg-config can discover the .pc files associated with the installed packages.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Command `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` gives:

```
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.15
```

Made this (but I think that the link is strange), but didn't solve the problem

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.15
```

Comment: Solved https://github.com/matthias-k/cyipopt/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

You must the following commands:

sudo apt-get install gcc g++ gfortran git patch wget pkg-config liblapack-dev libmetis-dev